# Day/Month Unit Transformation in R

Tags: r, date, transformation

Hey everyone the dates in my data frame looks like this:

```
0102
0103
0104
```

which translates to

```
January 2
January 3
January 4
```

Obviously not the most pretty way to display the date, so I wanted to transform that to something more readable. I used this code to try and do that:

```
as.Date(paste0("2018",date),format="%Y%m%d")
```

which I was hoping would separate the month and day to make it look a bit more cleaner and then also add the year 2018. EXCEPT this is what I got in return for those same 3 dates

```
2018-10-02
2018-10-03
2018-10-04
```

So I believe that it is ignoring that 0 in front of the "1" in the date "0104" so instead it's reading it as "10-4" instead of "01-04". Does anyone have a way to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're reading in `date` as a `numeric` which strips the leading `0`s. You can use `stringr::str_pad` to add them back.

```
date <- c(0102, 0103, 0104)

as.Date(
  paste0("2018", stringr::str_pad(date, 4, pad = "0")),
  format = "%Y%m%d"
)
#> [1] "2018-01-02" "2018-01-03" "2018-01-04"
```

However, it's probably best to read in `date` as a `character` so that stripping never occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sprintf` :

```
x <- c(0102, 0103, 0104, 0110)
as.Date(sprintf('2018%04d', x), '%Y%m%d')
[1] "2018-01-02" "2018-01-03" "2018-01-04" "2018-01-10"
```

You can also use `lubridate::ymd` to change to dates.

```
lubridate::ymd(sprintf('2018%04d', x))
```